# Shell Python vs WSGI Python execution times

Tags: python, django, performance, shell, time

I have spent a long time profiling some of my Django code (trying to find the root cause of a performance issue), which converts a queryset to a list of HTML  tags.

The queryset in question has around 8000 records, but profiling has shown that the database/SQL is not the issue, as the actual query executes in around 1 millisecond.

After many hours of trying to find the problem I accidentally stumbled upon the fact that running the specific code via Apache/WSGI seems to play a big role in the performance problem.

To narrow the issue down to a single line of Python code, I have wrapped it in a "clock" to measure it's performance, like so:

```
import time

start_time = time.clock()
records    = list(query_set)                  # <--- THIS LINE IS THE CULPRIT
total_time = time.clock() - start_time
with open('some_path/debug.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('%f\n'%total_time)
```

Ignoring the fact that I am converting an 8000+ record queryset to a Python list (I have reasons for doing so), the part I want to focus on is the timing differences:

```
Apache/WSGI:  1.184240000000000403446165365  (seconds)
From a shell: 0.6034849999999999381472548521 (seconds)
```

The code in question lives in a function that I can conveniently call from a Django management shell and run manually, which allows me to get the second timing metric.

So can someone please tell me what the heck is causing that doubling in execution time of that single line. Obviously a fair bit of built-in Django code is invoked by that line, but how can the way the code is executed make such a massive difference?

How can I get the same performance in Apache/WSGI as I get in the shell?

Note that I am running the Django application in daemon mode (not embedded mode) and the rest of my application is not suffering from performance issues. It's just that I never thought the difference between shell and Apache/WSGI would be a cause of performance difference, for this particular code, let alone any.

**Update 1**
I forgot to mention that I tried running the same code in nginx/uWSGI and the same problem occurred, so it doesn't seem to be Apache that's at fault. Possibly the way WSGI works itself?

**Update 2**
So the plot thickens...
That `list(query_set)` line of code is not multi-threaded by me, but if I alter my implementation slightly and do the actual iteration of the querset in multi-threaded code:

```
def threaded_func(query_set_slice): # Gets invoked by multiple threads created by me
    start_time = time.clock()
    for record in query_set_slice:
        ... do stuff ...
    total_time = time.clock() - start_time
    with open('some_path/debug.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('%f\n'%total_time)
```

... there is still an execution time difference (between shell and Apache/WSGI), but this time the ratio is reversed.
I.e. The numbers are:

```
Apache/WSGI: 0.824394 (seconds)
Shell:       1.890437 (seconds)
```

Funnily enough, as the ratio of the threaded function is the reverse of the previous ratio, the execution time of the function that invokes the threaded function is the same for the two types of invocation (Apache/WSGI and Shell).

**Update 3**
After doing some research on `time.clock()` it seems that it can't be trusted all the time, so I tried `time.time()` and that produced roughly a 1:1 ratio.
I also tried `LineProfiler` and that gave a 1:1 ratio, so my guess is that `time.clock()` is not taking into account context switches and things like that.

Comment: Can you run a `timeit`loop and do at least a few more iterations over that call? Also, why are you converting a queryset to a list, and not iterating over it?

Comment: I didn't take an average of 1000s of timings (mainly because it would take too long), but I did try it at least 10 times and got roughly around the same ratio each time. Do you still want me to try `timeit`? If so, how many iterations (bearing in mind that the worst case for a single iteration takes ~1.2 seconds). I am converting it to a list so that I can use multithreading/multiprocessing to parallelise the actual task of: queryset --> <option> tags. If I didn't parallelise it, that would be the bottleneck.

Comment: No, it sounds like you've got it covered, I was just curious.

Comment: I know it's hard to resist questioning why I am doing this computation, but I would really like to focus on the difference between invocations. E.g. I tried executing a recursive-non-cached fibonacci function via both ways and didn't get a 2:1 ratio, but got a ratio of about 17:24

Comment: don't use `time.clock()`; its behavior is platform-dependent. Use `timeit.default_timer` instead (it chooses the best of `time.clock`, `time.time`, `time.perf_counter` depending on OS, Python version).